# Why is the red ground light on, on my AVBar10 surge suppressor?

Tags: grounding-and-bonding, surge-suppression

I have a [Tripp Lite AVBar10](http://www.tripplite.com/en/products/model.cfm?txtModelID=4134) that shows two green LED on the outside ("protected" and "line OK") and a red LED in the middle ("ground").

I went to Lowes and got an outlet tester, and all the circuits checked out okay.
When testing the AVBAR10, it reads okay in all circuits on the strip.
I spoke with Tripp Lite and they sent me a replacement, but it reads the same.

Comment: According to the manual on the Tripp Lite site the ground LED **should** be lit if it is properly grounded. Why they make it red I don't know.

Comment: @Craig That sounds like *the* answer (RTFM). Please consider adding it as an answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: Thank you.  Regarding "RTFM" --  yeah I did, and I called them BUT nowhere does it say that two LEDS will glow GREEN and one LED wioll glow RED when everything is working.  Have you ever heard of a RED LED meaning things are AOK?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is "functioning to spec".  I think that is just how this surge suppressor works.

Why is it red? I know I have had basic suppressors in the past that only had a red ground light (no "line OK" or "protected" lights).  Perhaps they think people expect the ground light to be red.